# How to add suffix to all list member?

Tags: list

When I evaluate

```
(setq sample-list (list 'abc 'def))
(message "%s_suffix" sample-list)
```

Output is:

```
(abc def)_suffix
```

But I need to get:

```
abc_suffix def_suffix
```

How can I get the output?

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear just what you want - *return a list* with elements `abc_suffix` and `def_suffix`? Print each of those? Show them in the echo area (`message`)? Return a string of those separated by a space?

```lisp
;; Return a list with the suffix appended to each element.
(mapcar (lambda (ss) (format "%s_suffix" ss)) sample-list)
```

```lisp
;; Print, with the suffix appended to each.
(dolist (ss  sample-list) (princ (format "%s_suffix" ss)))
```

```lisp
;; Return the string "abc_suffix def_suffix".
(mapconcat (lambda (ss) (format "%s_suffix" ss)) sample-list " ")
```

```lisp
;; Show message in echo area, with the two separated by a space.
(message
  (mapconcat (lambda (ss) (format "%s_suffix" ss)) sample-list " "))
```

Comment: The list elements in the question are symbols, so `(symbol-name ss)` is needed (and then maybe `intern` depending, once again, on what the desired result happens to be).

Comment: @phils: Right, thx.

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way to achieve this via recursion:

```lisp
(defun print-list-with-suffix (lst)
  (cl-labels ((rec (x)
                   (unless (null x)
                     (message "%s_suffix" (car x))
                     (rec (cdr x)))))
    (rec lst)))

(setq sample-list (list 'abc 'def))

(print-list-with-suffix sample-list)
```

Comment: Recursion isn't idiomatic in Elisp ;).

Comment: @Basil you're right. But it will be once native compilation is merged into the master branch; tail-call optimization ftw

Comment: That's true, but with several caveats: even after nativecomp is merged, it's not guaranteed to be present in any given Emacs configuration, and tail recursion elimination apparently only happens at speed 3, so these optimisations can not be considered part of the Elisp language. Having said that, Emacs 28 has in the meantime gained a limited form of TCO for self recursion that works regardless of non/byte/native compilation. See these recent `emacs-devel` threads: https://lists.gnu.org/r/emacs-devel/2021-03/msg00775.html https://lists.gnu.org/r/emacs-devel/2021-01/msg00566.html